# Static local variables for methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, static, local

I have this:

```
def valid_attributes
  { :email => "some_#{rand(9999)}@thing.com" }
end
```

For Rspec testing right? But I would like to do something like this:

```
def valid_attributes
  static user_id = 0
  user_id += 1
  { :email => "some_#{user_id}@thing.com" }
end
```

I don't want `user_id` to be accessible from anywhere but that method,
is this possible with Ruby?

Comment: The short answer is no, there's no such thing as `static` in Ruby. Why not let the database handle your auto-incrementing key?

Comment: Because it's a method to generate valid attributes for Rspec testing, and some things must be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is a little larger in scope than your question, but I think it gets at the root of what you're trying to do, and will be the easiest and most maintainable.

I think what you're really looking for here is factories. Try using something like [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), which will make a lot of testing much easier.

First, you'd set up a factory to create whatever type of object it is you're testing, and use a sequence for the email attribute:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    sequence(:email) {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    # include whatever else is required to make your model valid
  end
end
```

Then, when you need valid attributes, you can use

```
Factory.attributes_for(:model)
```

You can also use `Factory.create` and `Factory.build` to create saved and unsaved instances of the model.

There's explanation of a lot more of the features in the [getting started document](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md), as well as instructions on how to add factories to your project.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitively check that gem out! ^^

Answer (score 8):

This is a closure case. Try this

```
lambda {
  user_id = 0

  self.class.send(:define_method, :valid_attributes) do
    user_id += 1
    { :email => "some_#{user_id}@thing.com" }
  end

}.call
```

Wrapping everything in lambda allows the variables defined within lambda to only exist in the scope. You can add other methods also. Good luck!

Comment: I tried your code by adding two `p valid_attributes` after it, but I got `Error NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`. I guess `user_id` inside `def` is a local variable initialized as `nil`. Maybe you can use the closure in another way. :)

Comment: Hi Sony, I've forgot about def. I've changed it to define_method already so it now should be able to access user_id. Other methods defined within lambda this way can also share the user_id variable.

Comment: Ok, but you must use `self.class.send :define_method, :valid_attributes`, since `define_method` is a private class method. Anyway, I prefer your solution over [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168400/static-local-variables-for-methods-in-ruby/7169076#7169076), because in my case `valid_attributes` is a proc (which must be called with `call` or `[]` in 1.8.7), and in your case it's a genuine method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a closure:

```
def validator_factory
  user_id = 0
  lambda do
    user_id += 1
    { :email => "some_#{user_id}@thing.com" }
  end
end

valid_attributes = validator_factory

valid_attributes.call  #=>  {:email=>"some_1@thing.com"}
valid_attributes.call  #=>  {:email=>"some_2@thing.com"}
```

This way `user_id` won't be accessible outside.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use an instance variable:

```
def valid_attributes
  @user_id ||= 0
  @user_id += 1
  { :email => "some_#{@user_id}@thing.com" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The only variables Ruby has are local variables, instance variables, class variables and global variables. None of them fit what you're after.

What you probably need is a singleton that stores the user_id, and gives you a new ID number each time. Otherwise, your code won't be thread-safe.